# Problem building a table for Machine Learning benchmarks

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to build a table to report benchmarks of tested machine learning models on different datasets. For my specific case, I'm considering three metrics on three different datasets.

```
\begin{table}[!h]
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
   \hline
   Models &
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Metric 1}} &
   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Metric 2}} &
   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Metric 3}} \\
   
   & D1 & D2 & D3 & D1 & D2 & D3 \\
   \hline

   Model1 &  1.03 & / & 1.60 & / & 2.30 & / \\
   \hline
   Model2 & \textbf{2.14} & \textbf{3.8} & \textbf{1.40} & \textbf{3.15} & 0.34 & 2.3 \\
   \hline
   Model3 & \textbf{3.45} & \textbf{1.50} & \textbf{3.15} & \textbf{1.2} & -2.15 & 3.00 \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

Below is the obtained result:

[image]

As I'm not too practical with LaTeX tables yet, I cannot easily figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

**EDIT**:

As suggested in the comments, I tried to add another triplet of datasets to match the total multicolumn number (9) but things are still not working:

CODE:

```
 \begin{table}[!h]
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
   \hline
   Models &
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Metric 1}} &
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Metric 2}} &
   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Metric 3}} \\

   & D1 & D2 & D3 & D1 & D2 & D3 & D1 & D2 & D3\\
   \hline
   Model1 &  1.03 & / & 1.60 & / & 2.30 & / \\
   \hline
   Model2 & \textbf{2.14} & \textbf{3.8} & \textbf{1.40} & \textbf{3.15} & 0.34 & 2.3 \\
   \hline
   Model3 & \textbf{3.45} & \textbf{1.50} & \textbf{3.15} & \textbf{1.2} & -2.15 & 3.00 \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: You only have two sets of D1/D2/D3 but three Metric headers, so the number of cells don't match (the multicolumns needs 9 in total but you provide only 6)

Comment: I tried to add another triplet of datasets but things are still not working.. I'm editing the question with the update

Comment: Now your column contents (10 cells) doesn't match your tabular specification (`|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|`, 7 cells).

Answer (score 3):

If you want couples of data under the three metrics, you need to declare seven columns and use `\multicolumn{2}{...}` for the header. If you triples you need to declare ten columns.

Never ignore errors.

Here are my proposals: one for triples and two for pairs; the last one is in caged format just to show that it's much less attractive.

I recommend using `siunitx` anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\sisetup{detect-all}
\NewDocumentCommand{\B}{}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Models & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Metrics} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-10}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{3} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
& {D1} & {D2} & {D3} & {D1} & {D2} & {D3} & {D1} & {D2} & {D3} \\
\midrule
Model1 &  1.03 & {/} & 1.60 & {/} & 2.30 & {/} \\
Model2 & \B 2.14 & \B 3.8 & \B 1.40 & \B 3.15 & 0.34 & 2.3 \\
Model3 & \B 3.45 & \B 1.50 & \B 3.15 & \B 1.2 & -2.15 & 3.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Models and metrics (triples of data)}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\sisetup{detect-all}
\NewDocumentCommand{\B}{}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Models & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Metrics} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-7}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
& {D1} & {D2} & {D1} & {D2} & {D1} & {D2} \\
\midrule
Model1 &  1.03 & {/} & 1.60 & {/} & 2.30 & {/} \\
Model2 & \B 2.14 & \B 3.8 & \B 1.40 & \B 3.15 & 0.34 & 2.3 \\
Model3 & \B 3.45 & \B 1.50 & \B 3.15 & \B 1.2 & -2.15 & 3.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Models and metrics (pairs of data)}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\sisetup{detect-all}
\NewDocumentCommand{\B}{}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}

\begin{tabular}{
  |l|
  S[table-format=1.2]|
  S[table-format=1.2]|
  S[table-format=1.2]|
  S[table-format=1.2]|
  S[table-format=-1.2]|
  S[table-format=1.2]|
}
\hline
Models &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Metric 1} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Metric 2} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Metric 3} \\
\cline{2-7}
& {D1} & {D2} & {D1} & {D2} & {D1} & {D2} \\
\hline
Model1 & 1.03 & {/} & 1.60 & {/} & 2.30 & {/} \\
\hline
Model2 & \B 2.14 & \B 3.8 & \B 1.40 & \B 3.15 & 0.34 & 2.3 \\
\hline
Model3 & \B 3.45 & \B 1.50 & \B 3.15 & \B 1.2 & -2.15 & 3.00 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caged models and metrics (pairs of data)}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have mismatch in defined number of spanned columns in `\multicolumn{}{}{}` command as well in used ampersands in table (as noted @Marijn in his comment.

Below is corrected your table code  (as I gueass what you after) and one example of use `tabullaray` and `siunitx` package in table writing:

```
\documentclass{article}
%-------------------------------- not needed in the first example
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx, varwidth}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}                          %
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
With \verb+\tabular+ environment;
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l |l|l |l|l |l|l|}
   \hline
Models  &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Metric 1}}  
                        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Metric 2}}  
                                        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Metric 3}} \\
        & D1    & D2    & D1    & D2    & D1            & D2    \\
    \hline   
Model1  & 1.03  & /     & 1.60  & /     & 2.30          & /     \\
    \hline
Model2 & \textbf{2.14}  
                & \textbf{3.8}  
                        & \textbf{1.40} 
                                & \textbf{3.15} 
                                        & 0.34          & 2.3   \\
    \hline
Model3 & \textbf{3.45}  & \textbf{1.50} & \textbf{3.15} & \textbf{1.2}  & -2.15 & 3.00  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

With use of the \verb+\tabularray+ and \verb+siunitx+ packages;
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \sisetup{detect-all}
  \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
               colspec = {l *{4}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=-1.2}]
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]
                         },
               row{1}  = {guard, font=\bfseries},
               row{1,2}= {guard}
                 }
   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    Models  
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Metric 1
                                        &           &  \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Metric 3 
                                                            &       \\
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    Metric 3 \\
        & D1    & D2        & D1        & D2        & D1    & D2    \\
Model1  & 1.03  & /         & 1.60      & /         & 2.30  & /     \\
Model2 &\B 2.14 &\B 3.8     &\B 1.40    &\B 3.15    & 0.34  & 2.3   \\
Model3 &\B 3.45 &\B 1.50    &\B 3.15    &\B 1.2     & -2.15 & 3.00  \\
  \end{tblr}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Apparently my guessing was wrong. Below are examples where are three triples of table contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
%-------------------------------- not needed in the first example
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx, varwidth}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}  
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
With \verb+\tabular+ environment;
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l |l|l|l |l|l|l |l|l|l|}
   \hline
Models  &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Metric 1}}  
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Metric 2}}  
                        &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Metric 3}} \\
        & D1    & D2    & D3    & D1    & D2    & D3    & D1    & D2    & D3    \\
    \hline   
Model1  & 1.03  & /     & 1.60  & /     & 2.30  & /     &       &       &       \\
    \hline
Model2 & \textbf{2.14}  
                & \textbf{3.8}  
                        & \textbf{1.40} 
                                & \textbf{3.15} 
                                        & 0.34  & 2.3   &       &       &       \\
    \hline
Model3 & \textbf{3.45}  & \textbf{1.50} & \textbf{3.15} & \textbf{1.2}  
                                        & -2.15 & 3.00  &       &       &       \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

With use of the \verb+\tabularray+ and \verb+siunitx+ packages:
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \sisetup{detect-all}
  \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
               colspec = {l *{4}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=-1.2}]
                            *{4}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}
                         },
               row{1}  = {guard, font=\bfseries},
               row{1,2}= {guard}
                 }
   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    Models  
        &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Metric 1
                &           &           &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Metric 2
                                                    &       &       &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Metric 3 
                                                                            &       &       \\
        & D1    & D2        & D3        & D1        & D2    & D3    & D1    & D2    & D3    \\
Model1  & 1.03  & /         & 1.60      & /         & 2.30  & /     &       &       &       \\
Model2 &\B 2.14 &\B 3.8     &\B 1.40    &\B 3.15    & 0.34  & 2.3   &       &       &       \\
Model3 &\B 3.45 &\B 1.50    &\B 3.15    &\B 1.2     & -2.15 & 3.00  &       &       &       \\
\end{tblr}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]